# Windows Phone 8.1 SQLite Using

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

How can i use that? In Windows Phone 8.1 project there is no System.Data namespace. In internet I could not found any documentation for SQLite to Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Are you using Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight or windows Phone 8.1 Universal app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install SQLite extension. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d97faf6-39e3-4048-a0bc-adde2af75d1b

[This tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/19) might help too.